# How to set an element's atribute from it's parent's attribute?

Tags: wpf, xaml

(I'm extremely new to xaml)

```
<Canvas Width="200" Height="100"> 
    <Rectangle Width="" Height=""></Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

Now, is it possible to set `Rectangle`'s Width and Height the same as `Canvas`'s using Xaml only?
or is necessary to use code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `Data Binding`. Looks like this:

```
<Canvas Name="myCanvas" Width="200" Height="100">
    <Rectangle Width="{Binding ElementName=myCanvas, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=myCanvas, Path=Height}"> </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```